# Is it possible to calculate the mass of gas remaining in a cylinder simply by measuring temperature and pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Given $pV=nRT$, where;

$p$ = Pressure, $V$ = Volume, $n$ = Number of moles of gas, $R$ = Gas constant and $T$ = Temperature in Kelvin.

Also, the mass can be calculated by;

$m = nM \rightarrow n = \frac{m}{M}$, where;

$m$ = mass, $n$ = Number of moles and $M$ = Relative molecular mass.

Putting these two equations together, I get;

$pV = \frac{mRT}{M} \rightarrow m = \frac{pVM}{RT}$.

Therefore I assume that as you release gas from that cylinder, you can calculate the mass of gas remaining in the cylinder simply by taking readings of the temperature and pressure in the cylinder.

Of course, this is assuming you know the volume of the cylinder, as well as it having just one gas, so you know the Relative atomic mass too.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, for an ideal gas.

Comment: @ChetMiller thanks for this answer. I understand what an ideal gas is and what the requirements are for a gas to be classed as an "ideal gas". However, one thing I don't 100% understand is at what point approximating the gas as an ideal gas breaks down, and therefore between what limits would this be accurate?

Comment: Are you familiar with the "principle of corresponding states," and the expression for the compressibility factor z as a function of reduced pressure and reduced temperature.

Comment: I was not previously aware of this until you mentioned it, but I have done a bit of research now on the internet regarding the value of z. How would this be used in this instance?

Comment: If z differs significantly from 1.0, the ideal gas law is inaccurate.

Comment: Okay. So is there a more accurate equation than the ideal gas equation to use for gases of high pressures for example? Or in any other situation where z is not particularly close to 1?

Comment: z = 1 is the definition of an ideal gas.  You need to research this yourself to get more of the details.  I recommend Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al.

Comment: You can go even further. In (ideal) processes you can always compute every single state variable including entropy (differences) based off 2 known variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right, at least you are if you take *M* to be the relative *molecular* mass. [The molecules of many gases, including oxygen, nitrogen and hydrogen, consist of more than one atom, bonded together.]

Comment: Thank you, yes I just edited that. I didn't realist I hadn't written that initially. Thanks for pointing this out.